# How does keras Embedding layer works if input value greater than input_dim?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer, embedding

How does Embedding layer works if input value greater than input_dim?

Why keras doesn't raise an exception?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(1, 2, trainable=True, mask_zero=False))
input_array = [5]

model.compile("rmsprop", "mse")

output_array = model.predict(input_array)

outpur_array
#array([[[0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

input value = 5
input_dim = 1

Documentation says that the input value(5) must be less than input_dim(1). In my example it is false, but code still raise no exception

Thank you!

Comment: You mean low input dimension and higher output dimension? What's wrong with that?

Comment: No. Documentation says that the input value(5) must be less than input_dim(1). In my example its false, but code still raise no exception.

Comment: I think you don't understand how embedding layer works in the first place, plus can you share the link where it exactly says that?

Comment: https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/

Comment: Embedding layer use lookup matrix with shape (input_dim, output_dim). where input dim number embedding vectors to be learned. When i pass index, layer takes vector by its index from Embedding matrix. Anything is wrong in my description?

Comment: check my answer maybe things will be clear.

Comment: What is the Keras version you are using? To find out, run: `import keras; print(keras.__version__)`. I got an error with Keras 2.3.1.

Comment: I reproduced your behaviour with keras 2.3.1 and added an updated answer, please look if it is reasonable.

Comment: my keras version is 2.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Embedding layer uses a lookup matrix with shape (input_dim, output_dim). where input dim number embedding vectors to be learned. When I pass the index, layer takes vector by its index from the Embedding matrix.**

Thanks for pointing out that I was getting confused with input_length with input_dim.

First of all, there is an error if you use tensorflow.keras.

**tensorflow**

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Input
import numpy as np

ip = Input(shape = (3,))
emb = Embedding(1, 2, trainable=True, mask_zero=True)(ip)

model = Model(ip, emb)
input_array = np.array([[5, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3]])

model.compile("rmsprop", "mse")

output_array = model.predict(input_array)

print(output_array)

print(output_array.shape)

model.summary()
```

[image]

But if I use keras 2.3.1, I don't get any error.

**keras 2.3.1**

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input
import numpy as np

ip = Input(shape = (3,))
emb = Embedding(1, 2, trainable=True, mask_zero=True)(ip)

model = Model(ip, emb)
input_array = np.array([[5, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3]])

model.compile("rmsprop", "mse")

output_array = model.predict(input_array)

print(output_array)

print(output_array.shape)

model.summary()
```

[image]

So, is keras broken? First thing to notice is keras and tensorflow.keras has different implementations for embedding layer. To validate that, let's go to keras embedding layer.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/embeddings.py#L16

For now let's just look into call function.

```
    def call(self, inputs):
        if K.dtype(inputs) != 'int32':
            inputs = K.cast(inputs, 'int32')
        out = K.gather(self.embeddings, inputs)
        return out
```

N.B: If you want the exact source code for keras 2.3.1 go here and download source code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases

But if we go to tensorflow implementation, it's different.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/embedding_ops.py

Just to verify, the call function is differently written.

```
  def call(self, inputs):
    dtype = K.dtype(inputs)
    if dtype != 'int32' and dtype != 'int64':
      inputs = math_ops.cast(inputs, 'int32')
    out = embedding_ops.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings, inputs)
    return out
```

Now, we can dig deeper to find the different behavior and pinpoint the source for which keras doesn't throw the error and tensorflow.keras does but let's make a simple point. Is keras embedding layer doing something wrong?

Let's design a simple network like before and observe the weight matrix.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input
import numpy as np

ip = Input(shape = (3,))
emb = Embedding(1, 2, trainable=True, mask_zero=True)(ip)

model = Model(ip, emb)
input_array = np.array([[5, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3]])

model.compile("rmsprop", "mse")

output_array = model.predict(input_array)

print(output_array)

print(output_array.shape)

model.summary()
```

The model gives the following output.

```
[[[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]]
(2, 3, 2)
Model: "model_18"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_21 (InputLayer)        (None, 3)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_33 (Embedding)     (None, 3, 2)              2         
=================================================================
Total params: 2
Trainable params: 2
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Okay, we are getting bunch of zeros but the default weight_initializer is not zeros!

So, let's observe the weight matrix now.

```
import keras.backend as K

w = model.layers[1].get_weights()
print(w)
```

```
[array([[ 0.03680499, -0.04904002]], dtype=float32)]
```

In fact, it is not all zeros.

So, why are we getting zeros?

Let's change our input to the model.

As the only in vocabulary word index for input_dim = 1, is 0. Let's pass 0 as one of the inputs.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input
import numpy as np

ip = Input(shape = (3,))
emb = Embedding(1, 2, trainable=True, mask_zero=True)(ip)

model = Model(ip, emb)
input_array = np.array([[5, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]])

model.compile("rmsprop", "mse")

output_array = model.predict(input_array)

print(output_array)

print(output_array.shape)

model.summary()
```

Now, we get non-zero vectors for the positions where we passed 0.

```
[[[ 0.          0.        ]
  [-0.04339869 -0.04900574]
  [ 0.          0.        ]]

 [[ 0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.        ]
  [-0.04339869 -0.04900574]]]
(2, 3, 2)
Model: "model_19"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_22 (InputLayer)        (None, 3)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_34 (Embedding)     (None, 3, 2)              2         
=================================================================
Total params: 2
Trainable params: 2
Non-trainable params: 0
```

In short, Keras maps any out of vocabulary word index with a zero vector and this is reasonable as for those positions the forward pass will ensure all the contributions are NIL (the biases may have a role though). That is a little bit counter-intuitive as passing out of vocabulary tokens to the model seems an overhead (rather than just removing them in the pre-processing step) and bad practice.

The lesson would be avoiding Keras altogether and shifting to tensorflow.keras as they clearly mention there will be less support and minor bug fixes after 2.2 versions.

The relevant issue at keras github repo: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13989

Comment: what do you think input_dim for?

Comment: You are interpreting it incorrectly. The `input_dim` is exactly the same as vocabulary size. Check the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/).

Comment: thanks for pointing out, how did I get confused with input_dim with input_length.

Answer (score 0):

Embeding layer is just a Dense layer, nothing is wrong with that. you are just performing a simple linear or affine transformation on data. input/output dimensions are arbitrary, the reason that using lower output dimension is more common in practice, lies on the fact that high dimensional data points usually have a lower dimensional manifold in their respective input dimension which most of the valuable informations lies on that manifold. this is the geometric Idea behind PCA or any other dimensionality reduction algorithm.

Overcomplete Autoencoders are in contrast a good example of a practical case where higher output dimension is desirable and the model is forced to learn useful representations by other means than projecting on lower dimensional subspaces, by constraints like sparsity and Lasso regularization for example.

Comment: No. Documentation says that the input value(5) must be less than input_dim(1). In my example its false, but code still raise no exception.

Comment: then give it a seequence of 1D inputs with different values, like [5, 4, 2], maybe it does not necessary mean for Embedding layer to use value of [1] , which makes total sense, why should the value relates to dimension, the total # of different values matter I guess.

Comment: if you pass [6656, 7878, 787, 7879, 7986785] you'll also get [0, 0] * 5

Comment: ok, I ran your code just now, it throws an Error as expected:
InvalidArgumentError:  indices[0,0] = 1 is not in [0, 1) ... , I omitted the rest of error. this is probably because you are using keras, instead of tf.keras.  I used tensorflow keras version and it worked as expected. I donno why the keras version did not work properly on your system. check if tf.keras works for you.